# Xamarin:Forms: Custom Picker List is very small compared to standart picker

Tags: xamarin.forms

this is my custom picker:

```xml
                    <local1:CustomPicker x:Name="picker_maincat_pickcate" 
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                TitleColor="#000000"
                                Title="Hauptkategorie"
                                FontFamily="arial"
                                BackgroundColor="#00000000"
                                TextColor="#272727"
                                HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                                VerticalOptions="Center">
                        <Picker.Items>
                            <x:String>Cat 1</x:String>
                            <x:String>Cat 2</x:String>
                            <x:String>Cat 3</x:String>
                            <x:String>Cat 4</x:String>
                            <x:String>Cat 1</x:String>
                            <x:String>Cat 2</x:String>
                            <x:String>Cat 3</x:String>
                            <x:String>Cat 4</x:String>
                        </Picker.Items>
                    </local1:CustomPicker>
```

On Android:

```cs
    [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomPicker), typeof(CustomPickerRenderer))]

    namespace App4.Droid.CustomComponents
    {

        class CustomPickerRenderer : PickerRenderer
        {

            public static void Init() { }
            protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Picker> e)
            {
                base.OnElementChanged(e);
                if (e.OldElement == null)
                {
                    Control.Background = null;

                    var layoutParams = new MarginLayoutParams(Control.LayoutParameters);
                    layoutParams.SetMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
                    LayoutParameters = layoutParams;
                    Control.LayoutParameters = layoutParams;
                    Control.SetPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
                    SetPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But the resulting list looks like this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0jGv.jpg)

So you see, the pop up that opens is very small. If I use the normal picker, the list takes up all the screen which is way better. 
How can I get a big list with a custom picker?

THank you!"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to achieve the result like following GIF?

[image]

If so, you should change your custom renderer like following code.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomPicker), typeof(CustomPickerRenderer))]
namespace PickerDemo.Droid
{

    public class CustomPickerRenderer : PickerRenderer
        {
        Context context;
        private IElementController ElementController => Element as IElementController;
        public CustomPickerRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }
            public static void Init() { }
            protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Picker> e)
            {
                base.OnElementChanged(e);
                if (e.OldElement == null)
                {
                    Control.Background = null;

                    var layoutParams = new MarginLayoutParams(Control.LayoutParameters);
                    layoutParams.SetMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
                    LayoutParameters = layoutParams;
                    Control.LayoutParameters = layoutParams;
                    Control.SetPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
                    SetPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);

                Control.Click += Control_Click;
                }
            }

        private void Control_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
            Picker model = Element;
            // Element


            string[] items = model.Items.ToArray();
            AlertDialog.Builder listDialog =
                new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            listDialog.SetTitle(model.Title ?? "");

            listDialog.SetItems(items, (sender, args) =>
            {

                ElementController.SetValueFromRenderer(Picker.SelectedIndexProperty, args.Which);
                if (Element != null)
                {
                    if (model.Items.Count > 0 && Element.SelectedIndex >= 0)
                        Control.Text = model.Items[Element.SelectedIndex];
                    ElementController.SetValueFromRenderer(VisualElement.IsFocusedProperty, false);
                    Control?.ClearFocus();
                }
                listDialog = null;
            });
            listDialog.SetNegativeButton("Cancel",(s, a) =>
            {
                ElementController.SetValueFromRenderer(VisualElement.IsFocusedProperty, false);
                Control?.ClearFocus();
                listDialog = null;
            }); 


            listDialog.Show();
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            Control.Click -= Control_Click;
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted. I thought about that it is possible building an alert but u pulled it through. Awesome and thanks alot. However, I have one more question: All my custom components (like yours) have a RED color for the buttons. (Cancel button) Why is this and how can I change that? Thank you!